# Can i make a .desktop app for a shell script not local?

Tags: scripts, python3, .desktop

I created a shortcut for a shell script with the extension `.desktop`. My desktop app runs a python code with double-click and it has it's own icon. Is a `.desktop` app only local? And can i make it not local so that it works and have the same icon i assigned when i send it to to another user?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I think you are asking "How do I change this .desktop file so Judy can run a copy of this script on her system, too." If so, one answer is to avoid user-specific paths. Put the script in a system path like /usr/local instead of /home/$USER/.local

Comment: https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Howto_desktop_files/  is probably of interest.

Comment: @user535733 Yes this is exactly what i meant, i want another user to run a copy of this script on her system. Are there any rules of changing my path to non-local?

Answer (score 1):

`.desktop` files are not shortcuts. They are files which describe what should be shown in the launcher/application-launcher.

### A sample desktop file

```
# Copyright (c) Rudra Saraswat
# The below sample desktop file is licensed under the BSD-3-Clause license.
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sample Desktop File for python3 script.
GenericName=Example
Comment=This is a sample desktop file.
Type=Application
Exec=python3 "<path-to-script>"
Icon=<gtk-icon>
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
Keywords=example;sample;
```

You can replace  with the icon from the GTK icon theme. A list of GTK icons in your icon theme can be found by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y yad && yad-icon-browser` in the terminal. YOu should then run `sudo update-desktop-database`.

### Redistributing your app

You can package your app as .deb package, or write a simple script which installs your python3. While deb packaging is a complicated, you can write a simple shell script which installs your app, like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Rudra Saraswat
# The below script is licensed under the BSD-3-Clause license.
[ ! "$EUID" -eq "0" ] || { sudo -p "Please enter your password to continue: " "$0" "$@"; exit $?; }
set -e
mkdir -p '/opt/' '/opt/mypythonscript/'
cat << 'EOF' > '/opt/mypythonscript/main.py'
<python-script-contents>
EOF
cat << 'EOF' > '/usr/share/applications/myfirstdesktopfile.desktop'
<desktop-file-contents>
EOF
update-desktop-database || true
echo "Installed mypythonscript."
```

You'll need to make the file executable with: `chmod +x <filename>` in the terminal, or select "Allow executing file as program" in Nautilus > Select the installation script which you wrote > Properties > Permissions > Execute.
If you are distributing this file over the Internet, note that the executable permissions will not remain, in which case you'll need to ask the user to run `chmod +x <downloaded_file>` in the terminal or select "Allow executing file as program" in Nautilus > Select the downloaded install script > Properties > Permissions > Execute.

**Important note: The above code hasn't been tested in any way and may lead to permanent and unrecoverable damage, in which case I'm not liable/reponsible in any way.**

Comment: I think the shebang has to be on the first line of the script to work, Linux looks at it, not bash. Since it's making/using restricted directories, it has to be run as root (with sudo). You have to assure that the script has execute permission too. I'm not sure what permissions a desktop file needs.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for reminding me to set the executable permission and change the order of lines in the script. To clarify your doubt: The Linux kernel parses the top line and tries to run the program. However, in some cases, bash does that work. The desktop file does not need any special permission as it is not executed, rather is parsed.